# Defining and manipulating help text for a path

Tags: 7

Ok, this is a very basic question. If I create a 'page' in drupal using 'add content'. Does this new page (and the path defined for it, say, through 'pathauto') automatically get registered with a callback as a menu item so I can reference it's path in a custom module somehow?

For example, I tried the following code. Case #1 doesn't show anything on that page (a page created the typical way through the admin UI). The second case displays the help text correctly when I go to admin > modules > mymodule and click the 'help' link.

So what's going on here?

```
function mymodule_help($path, $arg) {
  switch ($path) {
    case 'services/software-training/webinars':
      // Help text for the simple page registered for this path.
      return t('This is help text for the simple page.');

    case 'admin/help#testmodule':
      // Help text for the admin section, using the module name in the path.
      return t("This is help text created in the page example's second case.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quote from the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_help/7) (subheading *Parameters*):

> $path: The router menu path, as defined in hook_menu(), for the help that is being requested; e.g., 'admin/people' or 'user/register'. If the router path includes a wildcard, then this will appear in $path as %, even if it is a named %autoloader wildcard in the hook_menu() implementation; **for example, node pages would have $path equal to 'node/%' or 'node/%/view'**. For the help page for the module as a whole, $path will have the value 'admin/help#module_name', where 'module_name" is the machine name of your module.

This means that the following should work for you:

```
    function mymodule_help($path, $arg) {
      switch ($path) {
        case 'node/YOUR_NODE_ID':
          // Help text for the simple page registered for this path.
          return t('This is help text for the simple page.');

        case 'admin/help#testmodule':
          // Help text for the admin section, using the module name in the path.
          return t("This is help text created in the page example's second case.");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Of course! Thank you. I'm surprised I wasn't alerted to this very point when I mentioned 'pathauto' in my question. It makes total sense to use the node id as that's what the system uses.

Comment: Welcome! Glad it helped.